# Enter State error, Slick2d

Tags: java, graphics, state, slick2d, flappy-bird-clone

I am creating a flappy bird esque minigame. For some reason there is an error when I try to enter my actual "playing" state from the "menu" state and the "level" state holds it all together, a new error is thrown as it was working before. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Level state: holds it all together:

```
package gamepackage;
import org.newdawn.slick.*;
import org.newdawn.slick.state.*;


public class level extends StateBasedGame{
    public static final String gamename = "Flight 1.0 ";
    public static final int menu = 0;
    public static final int playing = 1;

    public level(String gamename){
        super(gamename);
        this.addState(new Menu(menu));
        this.addState(new Playing(playing));

    }

public void initStatesList(GameContainer gc)throws SlickException{
    this.getState(menu).init(gc, this);
    this.getState(playing).init(gc, this);
    this.enterState(menu);

}

public static void main(String args[]){

    AppGameContainer appgc;
    try{
        appgc = new AppGameContainer(new level(gamename));
        appgc.setDisplayMode(800, 550, false);
        appgc.start();

    }catch(SlickException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    }


}
```

My Menu State: Is where the player clicks play to enter the "playing" state:

```
package gamepackage;


import org.lwjgl.input.Mouse;
import org.newdawn.slick.*;
import org.newdawn.slick.state.*;

public class Menu extends BasicGameState{
    Image play;
     int xpos = Mouse.getX();
        int ypos = Mouse.getY();
    public Menu(int state){


    }

    public void init(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg)throws SlickException{
        play = new Image("res/play.jpg");

    }
    public void render(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, Graphics g)throws SlickException{
g.drawImage(play, 0, 0);


    }

public void update(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, int delta)throws SlickException{
     Input input = gc.getInput();

     if((xpos >= 0 && xpos <= 127) && (ypos>= 0 && ypos <= 33)){
         if(input.isMouseButtonDown(0)){
             sbg.enterState(1);
         }
     }

}
public int getID(){
    return 0;
}
}
```

Playing State, where the gameplay occurs:

```
package gamepackage;
import org.newdawn.slick.*;
import org.newdawn.slick.geom.Rectangle;
import org.newdawn.slick.state.*;
public class Playing extends BasicGameState{

    Image guy;
    Image bg1;
    Image bg2;
    Image bg3;
    Rectangle pr;
    Rectangle rect1, rect2, rect3, rect4, rect5;
    Rectangle rect1d, rect2d, rect3d, rect4d, rect5d;

    float bg1x = 0;
    float bg2x = 800;
    float bg3x = 1600;

    float x = 30, y = 90;
    float px = 30, py = y + 160;


    float rect1x = 1000, rect1y = 0;
    float rect2x = 1250, rect2y = 0;
    float rect3x = 1500, rect3y = 0;
    float rect4x = 1750, rect4y = 0;
    float rect5x = 2000, rect5y = 0;
    float rect1dx = 1000, rect1dy = 300;
    float rect2dx = 1250, rect2dy = 350;
    float rect3dx = 1500, rect3dy = 400;
    float rect4dx = 1750, rect4dy = 350;
    float rect5dx = 2000, rect5dy = 300;



    public Playing(int state){


    }

    public void init(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg)throws SlickException{
        bg1 = new Image("res/bg1.jpg");
        bg2 = new Image("res/bg2.jpg");
        bg3 = new Image("res/bg3.jpg");
        guy = new Image("res/PlaneMovie1.gif");



    }
    public void render(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, Graphics g)throws SlickException{

        g.drawImage(bg1, bg1x, 0);
        g.drawImage(bg2, bg2x, 0);
        g.drawImage(bg1, bg3x, 0);

        pr = new Rectangle(240, py, 135, 80);


        rect1 = new Rectangle(rect1x, rect1y, 50, 100);
        rect1d = new Rectangle(rect1dx, rect1dy, 50, 300);

        rect2 = new Rectangle(rect2x, rect2y, 50, 150);
        rect2d = new Rectangle(rect2dx, rect2dy, 50, 300);

        rect3 = new Rectangle(rect3x, rect3y, 50, 200);
        rect3d = new Rectangle(rect3dx, rect3dy, 50, 300);

        rect4 = new Rectangle(rect4x, rect4y, 50, 150);
        rect4d = new Rectangle(rect4dx, rect4dy, 50, 300);

        rect5 = new Rectangle(rect5x, rect5y, 50, 100);
        rect5d = new Rectangle(rect5dx, rect5dy, 50, 300);

        g.draw(rect1);
        g.draw(rect1d);
        g.draw(rect2);
        g.draw(rect2d);
        g.draw(rect3);
        g.draw(rect3d);
        g.draw(rect4);
        g.draw(rect4d);
        g.draw(rect5);
        g.draw(rect5d);
        g.drawImage(guy, x, y);
    }


   public void update(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, int delta)throws    SlickException{

    Input input = gc.getInput();

    if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_SPACE)){   y -= .3 ; py -= .3 ; }
    if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_SPACE) == false){  y += .4; py += .4;}
    if(rect1x == -100){rect1x += 1150; rect1dx += 1150;}
    if(rect2x == -100){rect2x += 1150; rect2dx += 1150;}
    if(rect3x == -100){rect3x += 1150; rect3dx += 1150;}
    if(rect4x == -100){rect4x += 1150; rect4dx += 1150;}
    if(rect5x == -100){rect5x += 1150; rect5dx += 1150;}

    //collision detection
    if(pr.intersects(rect1)){ System.out.println("eyyo.");}


    bg1x -= .20;
    bg2x -= .20;
    bg3x -= .20;

 rect1x-= .25;
 rect2x -= .25;
 rect3x -= .25;
rect4x -= .25;
 rect5x -= .25;
 rect1dx -= .25;
 rect2dx -= .25;
 rect3dx -= .25;
 rect4dx -= .25;
 rect5dx -= .25;



}
public int getID(){
    return 1;
}
}
```

Comment: could you post the error that is thrown..?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend changing your "level" state to follow proper utilization of slicks StateBasedGame.

Examine the wiki entry here on the slick wiki:
http://slick.ninjacave.com/wiki/index.php?title=Game_States

Notice the difference between the example given (specifically the class constructor method, and the initStateList() method) and what you have in your level class. Notice how there is no need to call state.init(gc, this), as adding a state calls the init method on it's own. It might be the answer to your problem as I've seen this similar situation before.